# Filter by updated with pymongo using AsyncIOMotorClient

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to create async queries in my Mongo database based on the `created` and `updated` fields.

If I use the sync mode using `pymongo.MongoClient` everything works as expected.

When I change, using the same database to get the client via `motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient` the where operation works properly for fields added directly by insert operations, but they no longer work with `created/updated` fields that are created by Mongo instead of us.

Is there anything that we need to consider regarding these fields to be able to search by them in async mode?